# adding an unknown number of numbers in java

Tags: java, addition

I have the following code below:

```
public class Classes {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
public static void main(String[] args) {
int sum = add(10,20);

System.out.println(sum);


// TODO code application logic here
    }


public static int add(int number,int number2){
int c = number + number2;
return c;
}

}
```

In this case i am adding 2 numbers together and returning them to my main method. I now want to alter this, but keeping to the same structure, a way of adding an unspecified number of numbers. For example if i wanted to add three numbers i would adjust the following to

```
public static int add(int number,int number2,int number3){
int c = number + number2 + number3;
```

I cant keep adding int numberx to public static int add(

so what do i do?

Comment: if you feel bad, look at this monster with 6 methods for add :) https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can submit an array of integers and then loop and summarize them.

```
public static int add(Integer... numbers) {
    int result = 0;
    for (Integer number : numbers) {
        result += number;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: this works perfectly, i have never seen Integer... used before. Does the three dots represent an array of integers?

Comment: You can also use the primitive type int instead of Integer. Yes, it basically means that you can add as many integer parameters as you want and it will the build an array out of it. Can be very handy sometimes :)

Comment: Yes that is a real handy tool, never seen it being used in any text. Great Stuff